# Kotlin native how to use external dll

Tags: windows, dll, kotlin

I need to write extension for some windows 10 app. It can be done via library, delivered in .dll file.

Is it possible to use dll library in kotlin native?
Do anybody have full, step by step, working example?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/interop-with-c.html